# How can i pass string from new form to form1 richtextbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In Form1

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddText at = new AddText();
    at.Show();
    richTextBox2.Text = at.text;
}
```

In new Form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class AddText : Form
    {
        public string text = "";

        public AddText()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddText_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            text = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click `button1` in the new form it does assign the text from `textBox1` to the variable text.

But it's not passing it to the `Form1.richTextBox2`.
I guess the problem is that I try to assign the text in `Form1` in the button click event:

```
richTextBox2.Text = at.text;
```

But this happen before the button `Click` event in the new form.
Where/how in `Form1` should I assign the text to `richTextBox2` ?

I used `ShowDialog()` it's working only when I close the new form window. Only when I close it I see the text in the `richTextBox2`. But I want to see the text in `richTextBox2` when I click the Ok(button1) button without closing the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form1

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  AddText at = new AddText(this);
  at.Show();
  richTextBox2.Text = at.text;
}

public void SetText(string text)
{
  richTextBox2.Text = text;
}
```

New form

```
  public partial class AddText : Form
  {
    private Form1 _form1;

    public AddText(Form1 form1)
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      _form1 = form1;
    }

    private void AddText_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      _form1.SetText(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.Close();
    }
  }
```